# How to determine Zodiac Sign in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I write this in flutter ? 
I have made this app in swift now I am making the app in flutter what's the best method to get the Zodiac sign. Thank You

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
    let d = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let m = calendar.component(.month, from: date)

    switch (d,m) {
    case (21...31,1),(1...19,2):
        return "aquarius"
    case (20...29,2),(1...20,3):
        return "pisces"
    case (21...31,3),(1...20,4):
        return "aries"
    case (21...30,4),(1...21,5):
        return "taurus"
    case (22...31,5),(1...21,6):
        return "gemini"
    case (22...30,6),(1...22,7):
        return "cancer"
    case (23...31,7),(1...22,8):
        return "leo"
    case (23...31,8),(1...23,9):
        return "virgo"
    case (24...30,9),(1...23,10):
        return "libra"
    case (24...31,10),(1...22,11):
        return "scorpio"
    case (23...30,11),(1...21,12):
        return "sagittarius"
    default:
        return "capricorn"
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
String getZodiacSign(DateTime birthdate) {
  const List<String> signNames = [
    "Capricorn",
    "Aquarius",
    "Pisces",
    "Aries",
    "Taurus",
    "Gemini",
    "Cancer",
    "Leo",
    "Virgo",
    "Libra",
    "Scorpio",
    "Sagittarius",
    "Capricorn"
  ];
  const List<int> signDays = [0, 22, 20, 21, 21, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 22, 22];

  if (birthdate.day < signDays[birthdate.month])
    return signNames[birthdate.month - 1];
  else
    return signNames[birthdate.month];
}
```

Comment: Neat solution, could you please provide some information how it works? 
Somehow i don't get it xD

Comment: love it. It's beautiful. Simple and clean.

Answer (score 3):

figured out with basic solution.

```
String getZodicaSign(DateTime date)  {
    var days = date.day;
    var months = date.month;
   if (months == 1) {
        if (days >= 21) {
            return "Aquarius";
        }else {
            return "Capricorn";
        }
    }else if (months == 2) {
        if (days >= 20) {
            return "Picis";
        }else {
            return "Aquarius";
        }
    }else if (months == 3) {
        if (days >= 21) {
            return "Aries";
        }else {
            return "Pisces";
        }
    }else if (months == 4) {
        if (days >= 21) {
            return "Taurus";
        }else {
            return "Aries";
        }
    }else if (months == 5) {
        if (days >= 22) {
            return "Gemini";
        }else {
            return "Taurus";
        }
    }else if (months == 6) {
        if (days >= 22) {
            return "Cancer";
        }else {
            return "Gemini";
        }
    }else if (months == 7) {
        if (days >= 23) {
            return "Leo";
        }else {
            return "Cancer";
        }
    }else if (months == 8) {
        if (days >= 23) {
            return "Virgo";
        }else {
            return "Leo";
        }
    }else if (months == 9) {
        if (days >= 24) {
            return "Libra";
        }else {
            return "Virgo";
        }
    }else if (months == 10) {
        if (days >= 24) {
            return "Scorpio";
        }else {
            return "Libra";
        }
    }else if (months == 11) {
        if (days >= 23) {
            return "Sagittarius";
        }else {
            return "Scorpio";
        }
    }else if (months == 12) {
        if (days >= 22) {
            return "Capricorn";
        }else {
            return "Sagittarius";
        }
    }
    return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like that

```
getZodiacSign(int day, int month) {
    if((month == 1 && day <= 20) || (month == 12 && day >=22)) {
      return "capricorn";
    } else if ((month == 1 && day >= 21) || (month == 2 && day <= 18)) {
      return "aquarius";
    } else if((month == 2 && day >= 19) || (month == 3 && day <= 20)) {
      return "pisces";
    } else if((month == 3 && day >= 21) || (month == 4 && day <= 20)) {
      return "aries";
    } else if((month == 4 && day >= 21) || (month == 5 && day <= 20)) {
      return "taurus";
    } else if((month == 5 && day >= 21) || (month == 6 && day <= 20)) {
      return "gemini";
    } else if((month == 6 && day >= 21) || (month == 7 && day <= 22)) {
      return "cancer";
    } else if((month == 7 && day >= 23) || (month == 8 && day <= 23)) {
      return "leo";
    } else if((month == 8 && day >= 24) || (month == 9 && day <= 23)) {
      return "virgo";
    } else if((month == 9 && day >= 24) || (month == 10 && day <= 23)) {
      return "libra";
    } else if((month == 10 && day >= 24) || (month == 11 && day <= 22)) {
      return "scorpio";
    } else if((month == 11 && day >= 23) || (month == 12 && day <= 21)) {
      return "sagittarius";
    } else {
      return "unknown";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have such an entity:

```
class Sign {
  Sign._(
    this.name,
    this.startDate,
    this.endDate,
  );

  static final Sign ARIES = Sign._(
    'Aries',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.march, 21),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.april, 19),
  );

  static final Sign TAURUS = Sign._(
    'Taurus',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.april, 20),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.may, 20),
  );

  static final Sign GEMINI = Sign._(
    'Gemini',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.may, 21),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.june, 20),
  );

  static final Sign CANCER = Sign._(
    'Cancer',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.june, 21),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.july, 22),
  );

  static final Sign LEO = Sign._(
    'Leo',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.july, 23),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.august, 22),
  );

  static final Sign VIRGO = Sign._(
    'Virgo',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.august, 23),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.september, 22),
  );

  static final Sign LIBRA = Sign._(
    'Libra',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.september, 23),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.october, 22),
  );

  static final Sign SCORPIO = Sign._(
    'Scorpio',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.october, 23),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.november, 21),
  );

  static final Sign SAGITTARIUS = Sign._(
    'Sagittarius',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.november, 22),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.december, 21),
  );

  static final Sign CAPRICORN = Sign._(
    'Capricorn',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.december, 22),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.january, 19),
  );

  static final Sign AQUARIUS = Sign._(
    'Aquarius',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.january, 20),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.february, 18),
  );

  static final Sign PISCES = Sign._(
    'Pisces',
    DateTime(0, DateTime.february, 19),
    DateTime(0, DateTime.march, 20),
  );

  final String name;
  final DateTime startDate;
  final DateTime endDate;

  static List<Sign> toList() => <Sign>[
        ARIES,
        TAURUS,
        GEMINI,
        CANCER,
        LEO,
        VIRGO,
        LIBRA,
        SCORPIO,
        SAGITTARIUS,
        CAPRICORN,
        AQUARIUS,
        PISCES,
      ];

  static Sign fromName(String name) {
    return toList().firstWhere(
      (Sign sign) => name != null && sign.name.trim().toLowerCase() == name.trim().toLowerCase(),
      orElse: () => null,
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() => name;
}
```

and determination function:

```
  Sign determineSign(DateTime date) {
    if ((date.month == DateTime.december && date.day >= Sign.CAPRICORN.startDate.day) ||
        (date.month == DateTime.january && date.day <= Sign.CAPRICORN.endDate.day)) {
      return Sign.CAPRICORN;
    } else {
      return Sign.toList().where((Sign sign) => _isDateInSign(sign, date)).first;
    }
  }

  bool _isDateInSign(Sign sign, DateTime date) {
    return sign.startDate.month * 100 + sign.startDate.day <= date.month * 100 + date.day &&
        date.month * 100 + date.day <= sign.endDate.month * 100 + sign.endDate.day;
  }
```